# Login to https website with Python with request

Tags: html, python-3.x

I'd like to access some content from https://bato.to/ that requires me to login first. Their login page is: https://bato.to/forums/index.php?app=core&module=global&section=login

I've opened chrome's web developer tools to inspect the POST that's sent when I click login. The 'Form Data' inside the POST is:

```
auth_key:880ea6a14ea49e853634fbdc5015a024
referer:https://bato.to/forums/
ips_username:startwinkling
ips_password:password1
rememberMe:1
```

So I've tried to implement this with the code:

**Code so far**

```
from requests import session
import re

AUTH_KEY = re.compile(r"<input type='hidden' name='auth_key' value='(.*?)' \/>")

payload = {
    'ips_username': 'startwinkling',
    'ips_password': 'password1',
    'rememberMe' : '1',
    'referer' : 'https://bato.to/forums/'
}

with session() as c:
    login_url = 'https://bato.to/forums/index.php?app=core&module=global&section=login'
    page = c.get(login_url)
    auth_key = AUTH_KEY.search(page.text).group(1)
    payload['auth_key'] = auth_key
    print("auth_key: %s" % auth_key)

    page = c.post(login_url, data=payload)
    page = c.get('https://bato.to/reader#4b57865eb3a9a9a6')
    print(page.text)
```

I believe I'm grabbing and passing in the auth_key properly since the code outputs:

```
auth_key: 880ea6a14ea49e853634fbdc5015a024
```

But the HTML that's printed out indicate that I haven't been able to successfully log in. What am I missing here?

Comment: Any reason not to use selenium? That is much more easy for this kind of efforts.

Comment: @Anthon I'm a newbie at coding so I wasn't sure what options there were and what was easiest. I saw various suggestions while searching up how to log in with python such as Selenium, RoboBrowser and BeautifulSoup. Since I had prior experience scraping with the requests library, I figured I'd try and use it to login as well.

That said, thanks for pointing out Selenium as a good option. I just tried it and the login process was very simple!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The URL you use for POST is not correct.**

The correct one should be `https://bato.to/forums/index.php?app=core&module=global&section=login&do=process`, it's not the same as login landing page, **notice the extra `do=process` part**.

**Codes:**

```
from requests import session
import re

AUTH_KEY = re.compile(r"<input type='hidden' name='auth_key' value='(.*?)' \/>")

payload = {
    'ips_username': 'startwinkling',
    'ips_password': 'password1',
    'rememberMe' : '1',
    'referer' : 'https://bato.to/forums/'
}

with session() as c:
    login_url = 'https://bato.to/forums/index.php?app=core&module=global&section=login'
    page = c.get(login_url)
    auth_key = AUTH_KEY.search(page.text).group(1)
    payload['auth_key'] = auth_key
    print("auth_key: %s" % auth_key)

    page = c.post(login_url + '&do=process', data=payload)
    page = c.get('https://bato.to/reader#4b57865eb3a9a9a6')
    print(page.text)
```

**P.S.** I would suggest you to **add some headers(not use default headers)** as well, you might not want to appear as `User-Agent: python-requests/1.2.3 CPython/2.7.3 Windows/7` on their analytics, also in case they set some limits on certain pages for "non-browser" visit.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me on the URL; Now I see I was supposed to pay attention to the URL in the POST page instead of assuming it was the login page. Also thanks for the tip about headers.